# Netbeans formatting code line to break in multiple lines

Tags: java, netbeans, format, netbeans-8

Given a code line like this:

```
[..]
    stampsCollector.addStamp(stampId, isFamous, isDamaged, currentlyAvailable, value);
[..]
```

is there a convenient way to reformat it into this in **Netbeans**?

```
[..]
    stampsCollector.addStamp(
       stampId, 
       isFamous, 
       isDamaged, 
       currentlyAvailable, 
       value
);
[..]
```

I don't really mind how this is accomplished: 
e.g. either during reformatting on-save, or by hitting a custom keyboard-shortcut in each line or by using a recorded macro ...

At the current moment, I keep finding me manually reformatting lots of code lines which is quite time consuming.

Comment: There is `ALT+SHIFT+F` but I don't know how much it will help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Formatting -> Language: Java -> Category: Wrapping
```

Select "Method Parameters" and set it to `Always`. Using `SHIFT + ALT + F` will now automatically break those lines.

Comment: Looks quite good - is there a way to change the behavior so that the first parameter is also formatted in a new line? I don't really like that the first parameter is printed next to the method name - not sure if you understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: @SebastianRiemer I get your point, but I'm not aware of any way to do this :/

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll use this feature - having a way to format method parameters in a standard way automatically is really great and saves a lot of time. I guess I'll get used to the first param not being printed in a separate line.

Answer (score 0):

Open file in any decent editor (notepad ++)
Replace ( with (\n with regex mode on.

Comment: Thanks, while I use notepad++ for many tasks, I don't think I'd want to use it in this scenario.

Comment: Netbeans should have an option to change the whole file.